# Allowing remote clients to build and run a Exe with minimal permissions

Tags: c#, .net, security, compilation

I would like external users to be able to build c# files via a web client and build and run them on the server and output content back to the user, just as how dot-net-fiddle does.

The problem comes around security, how can I allow for there code to not be malicious and start process's or write files?

I have had a look into Application trust level, is this a viable option? I would like something more standalone were I can easily change levels within the application to see the results immediately.

I have also had a look at these SecurityPermission's but cannot get anything to work.

```
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestRefuse, Assertion = true)]
```

Comment: See this post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2010/02/24/is-cas-dead-in-net-4/. Also, I would suggest running everything in the context of a restricted user account - make sure you pentest this - any mistake means you could be easily "owned".

Answer (score 0):

One option you might consider is docker. Now that Microsoft is releasing a dotnet docker container, you could do the build and execution in the isolated container, control resource usage, and the cleanup the entire container afterwards.